# Wordpress and JS Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Firstly here's the URL: http://isotopethemes.com/js-conflict/community-listings/naples/

I'm using [Savant Theme](http://themeforest.net/item/savant-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/8989659) to build a website, in the above page I use [BedStax](http://www.bedstax.com/) to get list of areas. To get list of areas I use the following code as custom field:

```
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bedstax.com/realtorData/featuredCommunities.php?state=FL&area=Bonita Springs%20/%20Estero"></script>
//-->
<script type="text/javascript">

var state = 'FL';
var area = 'Naples';
var idx = '583';
var agent = 'xxx';
var domain = 'xxx';

function setCommunity(community,communityName) {

    var cookieSet = window.state + "::" + window.area + "::" + window.idx + "::" + window.agent + "::" + window.domain + "::" + community + '::' + communityName;

    document.cookie='idxCookie=' + cookieSet + '; path=/';
    document.location.href = '/featured-communities-info';
}


jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery.ajax({
        url:"http://bedstax.com/realtorData/newFeatComm.php?state=" + window.state + "&area=" + window.area + "&idx=" + window.idx,
        dataType: 'JSONP', // Notice! JSONP <-- P
        success:function(json){
            $('.output').html(json);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("Error");
        },
    });
});

</script>
<div class="output">
</div>
```

The issue is wherever there this code generates list of areas all JS on the page stops working, on the above linked page the search bar pop slide down does not work. On this page: http://isotopethemes.com/js-conflict/about-2/ click the search bar and it slides down, same with the plus symbol on the top right corner.

I've looked into the console and get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: this.on is not a function (line 16 jquery.min.js).

I've been struggling for days, I can give you the wp-login id and password if you want, any help would be appreciate :)

Comment: I visited the site, clicked the search icon, didn't get any errors. What is supposed to happen that is not?

Comment: plz check this link: http://isotopethemes.com/js-conflict/about-2/, the search bar show up on this page

Comment: which javascript file do you have your code in that deals with the search form?

Comment: sorry for the delayed replay, but its not just the search form, all js code does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

This ended up being (after chatting for a minute) the jquery version.  Updating to 1.7 proved to be the solution.   (NOTE: 2.0.1 would break it again, so 1.7 was the sweet spot).

We left the encapsulation in the code, so I'm leaving it in the answer as well.

---

Try encapsulating your jquery and see if that helps at all.

```
(function($){
    $(function(){  

        $.ajax({
            url:"http://bedstax.com/realtorData/newFeatComm.php?state=" + window.state + "&area=" + window.area + "&idx=" + window.idx,
            dataType: 'JSONP', // Notice! JSONP <-- P
            success:function(json){
                $('.output').html(json);
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("Error");
            }
        });

    });   
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Actually I don't know, it could be anywhere in the entire theme's js and the error is from jquery file :(

Comment: It also give me this:
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html

Comment: Yes I've removed the comma, I'm using jquery 1.5.1. I can give you the login and password if you can have a look.